# Discrete convolution tabular method

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution

In the time discrete convolution the order of convolution of 2 signals doesnt matter :

$x_{1}(n)\ast x_{2}(n) =x_{2}(n)\ast x_{1}(n) $ When we use the tabular method does it matter which signal we put in the x axis(which signal's points we write 1 by 1 in the x axis) and which we put in the y axis(which signal's points we write 1 by 1 in the y axis)?

For example suppose we have the impluse response of a LTI system $h(n) =\delta(n) + 2\delta(n-1) + 4\delta(n-3) =  [1,2,0,4] $.If the input signal $x(n) = [0,1,2,3,4]$ find output $y(n)$ of the system

[image]

Now if we write $h(n)$ in the x axis and $x(n)$ does the result change?

Comment: What is the tabular method of time-discrete convolution?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_kwjJLepLg

Comment: So you want people to waste their time watching a YouTube video instead of making an effort yourself to explain what the method is, and where exactly you are having difficulty in using it?

Comment: The commutative property is a property of some operation (convolution in this case), and it will definitely not be changed by the method you use to implement that operation.

Comment: @DilipSarwate ok I will edit